# How to store captured image inside photolibrary using sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to save the captured image inside the photo library. I tried to show the captured image inside the image tag.

```
handler : function(button, event) {
                Ext.device.Camera.capture({
                    source : 'camera',
                    destination : 'data',
                      quality: 100,
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                    success : function(imagedata) {
                        var img = Ext.getCmp('largeImage');
                        img.setSrc('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imagedata);
                    },

                    failure : function() {
                        Ext.Msg
                                .alert('Error',
                                        'There was an error when acquiring the picture.');
                    },
                    scope : this
                });
            }
```